# Встретились и скучковались "что", "чтобы" и "бы", - как их разредить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, тавтология

> **Что** трогательно – несмотря ни на **что**, все жильцы как один хвалили владельцев… Вот и я хотела **бы**, **чтобы** тот, кто вправе,
>   отвёл **бы** меня туда – где заброшенный колодец, стены, увитые
>   плющом, где пиньи и пальмы и немножко неба над морем…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Несмотря ни на что, все жильцы как один хвалили владельцев - это было
>   трогательно.
>
> Вот и мне хотелось (или "до сих пор хочется"), чтобы тот, кто вправе, отвёл
>   (бы) меня туда, где заброшенный колодец, стены, увитые плющом, где
>   пиньи и пальмы и немножко неба над морем.

"Бы" здесь нужно только в случае осознанной нереалистичности желания. Первое "бы" в оригинале указывает на пожелание в *настоящем* времени (это имел в виду автор - что и сейчас хочется?), реалистичное, но ленивое.